# How can I make the maximum value of two arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays

The app has 2 arrays. They are related among themselves. The user may choose 
a few item of array "countries", then maximum position of choosed items are displayed on second activity. For example user choose "Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", and then 
 the maximum position (6770000) displayed on second activity. How to make this ?

```
package com.example.1.2; 

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.browse.MediaBrowser;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main1Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

public static final String KEY_AVERAGE = "average";
String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
Button btnSubmit;
int sum;
ListView countriesList;
int average;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
    }

    countriesList = findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);
    countriesList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);


    btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
}

  public void onClick(View view)  {

               SparseBooleanArray checked = 
  countriesList.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
            if (checked.valueAt(i))
```

// The code that make the maximum position of user choosing may be here

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_AVERAGE, average);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public class Main2Activity extends Main1Activity {

TextView tvView;
int average;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    maximum = mIntent.getExtras().getInt(Main1Activity.KEY_MAXIMUM, 
maximum);
    tvView.setText("Maximum: " + maximum);
}
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `Map<String, Integer>` instead of two separate arrays?

Comment: How you store selection (in which structure)?

Comment: @MTCoster, I'm using a Map<String, Integer>

Comment: @Boken. Sorry. I forgot insert the part of code. Now this part is there

Comment: Why don't you take take an object array instead of map and then populate your list using that and on click correspondingly update the current max value on click of list item.

Comment: @Rajat Beck, I'm new in java. Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to store the indexes of matched countries. Lets say, countries that user submitted are stored in and `Array userChoice` and indexes of these countries in `Array countries` are stored in `Array matchedIndexes. Following code do this:

1. Stores the index of user's submitted countries.
2. Compare the population on those indexes and return maximum population

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
    int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};

    // suppose user selected these countries
    String[] userChoise = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica"}; 
    int maxPopulation = findMaxPopulation(countries, population, userChoise);
    System.out.println(maxPopulation);
}

public static int findMaxPopulation(String[] con,int[] pop,String[] choice)
{
    // indexes of countries in "Countries array" that submitted by user
    int[] matchedIndexes = new int[choice.length]; 
    int j=0; // for incrementing Array matchedIndexes
    int max = 0; // will return the maximum population

    for(int i =0;i<choice.length;i++){
        if(con[i].equals(choice[i])){
            matchedIndexes[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    // making comparision of population of submitted countries
    max= pop[matchedIndexes[0]];
    for(int i=0;i<matchedIndexes.length -1;i++){
        if(max<pop[matchedIndexes[i+1]])
            max = pop[matchedIndexes[i+1]];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: // suppose user selected these countries
    String[] userChoise = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica"}; 
    int maxPopulation = findMaxPopulation(countries, population, userChoise);
    System.out.println(maxPopulation); Why is it here ? Activity 1 has countries list. This list has multiple choice. The userChoise list is not statical

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get what you trying to say. Please be a bit more clearer.

Comment: I mean array "String [] userchoice" is May be not {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica"};". I ask you what function this part of code has ?

Comment: Yes of course, it may not be what I used, but you can save what user's submitted in an "Array". This is not a big job to save something in an array.